# C++ condition variable wait_for not behaving as expected

Tags: c++, c++11, condition-variable, c++-chrono

I am having a problem understanding why a test case that I think should be passing is failing most of the time. I have distilled the test down to the condition variable and using the wait_for method, specifically testing it to see if it does indeed wait for at least as long as the specified duration.

The test code snippet is below:

```
TEST_CASE("Condition variable test")
{
    std::mutex m;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool ex = false;
    std::chrono::milliseconds rel_time(50);

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    cv.wait_for(lock, rel_time, [&ex] {return(ex);});

    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    REQUIRE(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() >= rel_time.count());
}
```

I would expect from my understanding of the C++11 standard that this should pass all of the time. Ironically, if I change the clock type to the system clock I cannot get the test to fail.

An excerpt from [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com) for the condition_variable::wait_for method states that "If pred is specified (2), the function only blocks if pred returns false, and notifications can only unblock the thread when it becomes true (which is especially useful to check against spurious wake-up calls). It behaves as if implemented as:
return wait_until (lck, **chrono::steady_clock::now()** + rel_time, std::move(pred));"

Which implies to me that using the steady clock to take my reference time stamps is the correct clock.

I am compiling using the MinGW environment with the gcc 4.8.2 compiler.

Comment: Collin, start and end are time_points. I am subtracting the time points to form a duration. I am comparing the measured duration to the desired duration. The resolution on my system is sufficient for this measurement. I have increased the desired duration to both 500ms and 5s and the test still fails. I would still be curious to know more details relating to why you think this is a bad test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in your vendor's implementation.  I don't see how this test can fail.

Fwiw, your `REQUIRE` statement can be greatly simplified:

```
REQUIRE(end - start >= rel_time);
```

Comparisons among `durations` are *always* exact.

There is one way your test, as written, could fail:  If `std::chrono::steady_clock::duration` is larger than milliseconds, the expression `duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start)` could result in 0ms.  To protect against such a poor implementation you could add:

```
static_assert(std::chrono::steady_clock::duration{1} <= std::chrono::milliseconds{1},
    "This steady_clock implementation has an outrageously coarse duration");
```

Comment: This can easily fail if `steady_clock` has, for example, 16 ms resolution. The `wait_for` could delay for 64 ms, even though you requested 50 ms.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee And that would fail the test how?

Comment: @CollinDauphinee:  If the `wait_for` delays for 64 ms, then the test as written passes, assuming `REQUIRE` is a good name.

Comment: Howard, the reason I added the count() method was that the test framework I am using (Catch) cannot, as far as I know, expand a duration in the failure scenario. The result of count() can be expanded so I can see a representation of the actual comparison ("24 >= 50" in one case).

Comment: @JeffRoekle:  How unfortunate.  While I don't see a problem in this case, the manual conversions and escape to `count()` are an opportunity for bugs.  In other uses keep in mind that `duration_cast` will truncate towards zero.  This can have unexpected effects if the value being truncated is negative (which it can't in this example).  If you find yourself needing other rounding modes (e.g. `floor` -- truncate towards negative infinity), here are some utilities: http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html

Comment: @HowardHinnant: First, thank you for the reference link. Second, I was under the impression that the ratio of the time_point's internal duration was implementation dependent and that I needed to use the duration_cast in order to compare it to a duration with a fixed ratio, milliseconds for example.

Comment: @JeffRoekle:  Nope. When doing comparisons (or arithmetic) the `chrono` library will convert both operands to the `common_type` duration which is a duration both operands will convert to with no truncation error, and then perform the operation.  If by some chance `std::chrono::steady_clock::duration` is coarser than milliseconds on this implementation (which would be hard to swallow), the `duration_cast` could truncate `end-start` to 0ms.  You could add a `static_assert` to confirm that isn't true.  I'll update my answer with instructions on how to do that.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Thanks, I will be very happy to drop the duration_cast from my code.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Incidentally, after removing the duration_cast the tests pass, so it appears that the rounding the duration_cast was doing broke the test. Thank you again.